# Writting and reading a custom variable to a file in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to write and then read a variable to a file. The variable is from a data type created by me.

(*If helps:*

> type sys =
>       File of string * string list   | Folder of string * sys list ;;

)

How can I do this?
I've been reading about the use of fprintf, but for what I get it'd had to be converted somehow into a String first, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are sure your type will not change, you can use `input_value` and `output_value` from [Pervasives](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html).

```
let write_sys sys file =
  let oc = open_out file in
  output_value oc sys;
  close_out oc

let read_sys file =
  let ic = open_in file in
  let sys : sys = input_value ic in
  close_in ic;
  sys
```

`read_sys` will break whenever you will try to read value stored with an other version of `sys` (or if you change your version of OCaml between writing and reading).

If you want safety, you can use automatic serializer such as [sexplib](https://bitbucket.org/yminsky/ocaml-core/wiki/Home) (if you want to be able to read the file you are creating) or [biniou](http://mjambon.com/biniou.html) for efficient conversion.

Comment: Alright, that'd do just fine, at least for now.
Thank you very, very much!

Comment: @EBM: If this post answers your question, you should accept it to help future visitors.

Comment: @pad Yep, sorry, I must have forgotten back then.